# JS validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

My validation function looks like that.

```
var fname = $("#fname").val();
var lname = $("#lname").val();

function validate() {
    var isValid = true;
     if (!fname) {
            $("#fname").attr('class', 'invalid');
            isValid=false;
        }

    if (!lname) {
        $("#lname").attr('class', 'invalid');
        isValid=false;
    }
```

It simply changes the class of unfilled input box.

I know that i can write `else` for every `if` and change back to default (`class="valid"`) if user fills some of inputs. But how can i create something universal for all inputs to change back to default class the input that user has filled after first validation error?

Comment: you can use `addClass` method. add `invalid` class to object `$('your_selector').addClass('invalid')` and after validation just use `$('your_selector').removeClass('invalid')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was good Tural! HOWEVER, why the excess processing in your code? That will add unecessary stress. Since you, for what you "solved", will add the "valid" class to ALL the input type text or password, just add that to the actual input element in the straight code:

```
<input class='valid' ..... />
```

Now, back to your original validation: why not make it universal?:

```
function validate(formField) {
    if !formField $('#'+formField).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}
```

Or something in that vein ...

Comment: I already added valid class + read my answer, once more. That is the keypress function, "will add the "valid" class to ALL the input type text or password"- it will add valid class only when user presses the key

Comment: One of the ways would be: form .... onSubmit='validateIt(this);' and a validate it would go through the items in the form and send each item to validate(item). Ex.: function validateIt(formID) { for each ... validate(item) ... }

Comment: The `if !formfield` bit is not syntactically valid.  Would removing those two tokens be closer to what you're trying to do.

Comment: What did you fix? SO should have the ability to just strike out what the so called "editors" fix. Now I don't know how much I can trust you (not that I don't) to have fixed ... a problem that did not exist ... for 13 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can either assume everything is valid and then try to disprove that or you can try to prove its validity.  The below takes the first approach and sets all the classes to "valid" to be consistent with that.

```
function validate() {
  // Get the current form input state.
  var fname = $("#fname");
  var lname = $("#lname");

  // Assume everything valid until proven otherwise.
  var isValid = true;
  fname.attr('class', 'valid');
  lname.attr('class', 'valid');

  if (!fname.val()) {
    fname.attr('class', 'invalid');
    isValid=false;
  }

  if (!lname.val()) {
    lname.attr('class', 'invalid');
    isValid=false;
  }

  return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the way

```
  $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').keypress(function () {
        $(this).attr('class', 'valid');
});
```